# if composition $f\circ g$ is a function then both $f,g$ are functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

> let $f\subseteq A\times B$ and $g\subseteq B\times C$ to be relations such that $f\circ g$ is a function. So $f$ and $g$ are also functions.

I tried to think of an example that disproves it but every example that I tried does not disprove it. so I guess this theorem is valid and I'll be glad to hear some guidelines on how to prove it.

Comment: It’s not a theorem, it’s a statement. (“Theorem” implies it is proven)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Try $A,C$ sets with a single element. If $f= A \times B$ and $g=B \times C$, and $B \neq \emptyset$ then $f \circ g$ is a function.

Comment: $A=\{x\}$, $C=\{y\}$, $B=\{a,b\}$, $g=\{(x,a)\}\neq\emptyset$, $f=\{(b,y)\}\neq\emptyset$, then $f\circ g=\emptyset$ is not a function from $A\to C$.

Comment: @egorovik Ty. fixed :)

Comment: It wasn't false before, just that $f\circ g$ doesn't end up being a function between the sets that one expects. The question itself didn't specify.

Comment: @egorovik Yea I know, I was just trying to state something too general, which was not true in the full generality :)